# why do I need two click two times to trigger onclick event with angular8 and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseevent, angular8

why do I need two-click two times to trigger on click event with angular8 and jquery

//.ts

```
addActive1() {
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.arrow').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('arrow-clicked');
  });
});
```

}

//.html

```
<a (click)="addActive1()" class="arrow shadow-lg">
```

Comment: You do you use both jquery and angular? And you bind the event twice?! what the point?

Comment: what I need to to add the class "active" to the clicked a tag sibling and when I remove the jquery onclick it doesn't trigger the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few searches, I've found the perfect answer that worked for me in my case.
let me explain my case first, I have 3 boxes for Mission, VIsion, etc..., Every box has a fixed height, And if I clicked on the arrow to expand they must fit 100% of text inside it.
when I created it as a static page it worked fine, But when I looped using ngFor it didn't work.

**So I've found this answer**

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow', function () {
      $(this).siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('arrow-clicked');
      console.log('Clicked!');
});
```

As you can see, The problem was I used 2 functions inside each other, So it triggered 2 times, So I switched the **$('.arrow')** to **$(document)**. and used only jQuery on click.